# Using rails-sqlserver-adapter to display data in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Awesome tool, I plugged into a SQLServer 2008 with little trouble and 
figure out how to execute a SP from rails console, but I don't know where 
to go from here :(

This seems like a silly question to ask, but I'm pretty new to 
development so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here's how I ran the SP (PD_DE_getSegmentProfile) from console:

```
$ PdDeSegmentMaster.execute_procedure :PD_DE_getSegmentProfile, 23, 'all' 

Execute Procedure (49.6ms)  EXEC PD_DE_getSegmentProfile 23, 'all' 
 => [{"segment_code"=>"23", "profile_element"=>"age_range", 
"Value"=>"35-54"}, {"segment_code"=>"23", 
"profile_element"=>"avg_HH_size", "Value"=>"4.10"}
```

I know that's a hash, but I've no idea how to call it from my app, 
display it in a view, et cetera. I'm not really concerned with storing 
it since I can just recall the SP to get it again. Where do I put the 
SP call in the app? Controller? Model?

database.yml, externaldb.rb (model) and the basics needed to set up the connection are all good, just need to move the returned hash to the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its best to move business logic to model.

Lets us say you are using the controller "PdDeSegmentMastersController"

```
class PdDeSegmentMasterController < ActionController
  def get_segment_profile
    @segment_profiles = PdDeSegmentMaster.get_segment_profile
  end 
end
```

In your model "PdDeSegmentMaster"

```
class PdDeSegmentMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
 #write a method to execute you stored procedure
  def self.get_segment_profile
    self.execute_procedure :PD_DE_getSegmentProfile, 23, 'all'
  end
end
```

In your view "get_segment_profile.html.erb"

```
<% if @segment_profiles.present? %>
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>segment_code</th>
   <th>profile_element</th>
   <th>Value</th>
 </tr>
 <% @segment_profiles.each do | segment_profile| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= segment_profile["segment_code"] %></td>
    <td><%= segment_profile["profile_element"] %></td>
    <td><%= segment_profile["Value"] %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
</table> 
<% else %>
 <h1>No segment profiles found!</h1>
<% end %>
```

Let me know if you still have any blocks.